# redux-form SubmissionError not updating error state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm having trouble setting up a simple form that shows validation only on submission with `redux-forms SubmissionError` (similar to what's shown in the [official RF docs example](https://codesandbox.io/s/qlop4l483q)).

The `errors` prop is always being `undefined` for the given `Field` component, even when the submit function *only* throws `SubmissionError` (as seen below).

I was initially on `v6.8.0`, but updated to `v7.3.0` and noticed the same behavior:

```
class Login extends React.Component {

  ...

  onEmailSubmit = values => {
    return Promise.resolve(true).then(() => {
      throw new SubmissionError({
        email: 'Invalid email address'
      })
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onEmailSubmit)}>
        <Field
          name='email'
          type='text'
          component={Input}
          label='Email'
          placeholder='Please enter your email address'
        />
        <Button type='submit'>
          Next
        </Button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

In the store, there's no indication of an error state upon submit:

[image]

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: How does your `Input` component look like?

Comment: hey, I don't believe that the store has the error values when the validation is applied on submit. When they are on the field level yes, there's a `syncErrors` object. Have a look at your Connected Field, in the React debugger on Chrome and see what props it has. Under  `meta` there should be an error object. If that object is present with values, then you know the validation happened

Answer (score -1):

A little late but try to do this with await and throw the SubmissionError below it